# Explanation of transition from summation to integral

Tags: calculus

I have seen the following derivation:

$\displaystyle \frac{2}{m \alpha}\sum_{i=1} ^{m-1} \frac{1}{i} = \frac{2}{m \alpha}\sum_{i=1} ^{m-1} \frac{1}{i} (i+1-i) \simeq \frac{2}{m \alpha} \int_{1} ^{m-1} \frac{1}{t} dt = \frac{2 \log(m-1)}{m \alpha}$

Why can we switch it this case from a summation to a integral?

Comment: I think it depends on what $\simeq$ means.  That is not a universally agreed upon symbol.  What does it mean in your context?

Comment: I think the LHS is a Reimann Sum for the integral.  Yes that seems to make sense.  So $\simeq$ just means "apprxoimately"

Comment: It should be a approximation of the summation for big values of $m$.

Comment: Right, exactly as Riemann sum is.